# Unable to see textbox in Gmail chat window

Tags: gmail, chat

I logged into Gmail this morning and opened the chat and was stunned to see that the textbox in the chat window is not visible at all. Even if I pop out the chat window, I still cannot see the textbox. I tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE and the issue persists.

Here are the screenshots. **The highlight in the images is to obfuscate the names. The issue is that I can't see the textbox to type my chat messages in**.

**Inside Gmail:**

[image: Inside Gmail]

**Popped out chat window:**

[image: Popped out chat window]

Any ideas of why this might be happening?

**Edit:**: I have tried changing screen resolution and dragging the chat window, but it did not help.

Comment: I started editing your question, but I can't tell what you're asking. Based on the highlighting in the screenshots, it looks like you're referring to the illegible text, but your question mentions textboxes. Are there supposed to be visible boxes in the blank white areas?

Comment: The highlighting was to obfuscate the names. Sorry about that. What I wanted to know was why the textbox-to-enter-messages is not visible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official Google chat forums, this [thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/chat/thread?tid=64ba081af7f5d6ca&hl=en&search_impression_id=c54be060587dfe6c:133a0ade04b&search_source=related_question) specifically, I found that this might be due to **adblockplus**. However, I have had **adblockplus** turned on in gmail all the while and did not face the issue until now. Now the issue has resolved itself somehow.